# Creating XML structure using xml attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to solve a puzzle with xml attributes. The problem is that we already have widely used file with this structure, from which I can't deviate

```xml
<CONFIGS>
  <CONFIG>
    <NAME>c1</NAME>
    <DB>
      <VAL1>v1</VAL1>
      <VAL2>v2</VAL2>
      <VAL3>v3</VAL3>
    </DB>
  </CONFIG>
  <CONFIG>
    <NAME>c2</NAME>
    <DB>
      <VAL1>v1</VAL1>
      <VAL2>v2</VAL2>
      <VAL3>v3</VAL3>
    </DB>
  </CONFIG>
</CONFIGS>
```

I've created this c# code

```cs
// master class
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CONFIGS")]
public class MyConfigs
{

    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "CONFIG", Type = typeof(MyConfigSchema))]
    public MyConfigSchema[] Schemas { get; set; }
}

// I should have array of these
public class MyConfigSchema
{

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DB", Type = typeof(Db))]
    public Db Config { get; set; }

    // this element is single and has subelements
    public class Db
    {

        [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "VAL1")]
        public string Val1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "int", ElementName = "VAL2")]
        public int Val2 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "VAL3")]
        public string Val3 { get; set; }

    }
}

// Writing 
using (var writer = new FileStream(testfile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfigs));
            ser.Serialize(writer, confFileObj);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Here is my issue - it writes the following output, which is almost what I need but in there it writes `<Schemas>. . . </Schemas>` that I can't have.

> `<CONFIGS>
>       --<Schemas>--
>         <CONFIG>
>           <NAME>c1</NAME>
>           <DB>
>             <VAL1>v1</VAL1>
>             <VAL2>v2</VAL2>
>             <VAL3>v3</VAL3>
>           </DB>
>         </CONFIG>
>         <CONFIG>
>           <NAME>c2</NAME>
>           <DB>
>             <VAL1>v1</VAL1>
>             <VAL2>v2</VAL2>
>             <VAL3>v3</VAL3>
>           </DB>
>         </CONFIG>
>       --</Schemas>--
>     </CONFIGS>`

Is there a way of get rid of `<Schemas>. . . </Schemas>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just solved it. I have never seen this before, looked on MSDN, hence I didn't try it. But I tried instead of this

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "CONFIG", Type = typeof(MyConfigSchema))]
public MyConfigSchema[] Schemas { get; set; }
```

do this

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "CONFIG", Type = typeof(MyConfigSchema))]
public MyConfigSchema[] Schemas { get; set; }
```

Instead of `XmlArrayItem` I placed `XmlElement` and it worked. I didn't know one can mark List or array with plain element attribute.