# Improve function to fill object from string with tag

Tags: xml, vb.net

I would like to fill an object with my string data that looks like XML. I've tried with RegEx and it works but it's very ugly.

My string looks like this:

```xml
<Item1*>XXXXXX</Item1*>
<Item2*>XXXXXX</Item2*>
<DOC*>
<DOC_ID*>XXXXXX</DOC_ID*>
<DOC_TYPE*>XXXXX</DOC_TYPE*>
</DOC*>
<HU*>
<HU_X1*>XXXXXX</HU_X1*>
<HU_Y1*>XXXXXX</HU_Y1*>
<HU_Z1*>XXXXXX</HU_Z1*>
</HU*>
<HU*>
<HU_X2*>XXXXXX</HU_X2*>
<HU_Y2*>XXXXXX</HU_Y2*>
<HU_Z2*>XXXXXX</HU_Z2*>
</HU*>
<HU*>
<HU_X3*>XXXXXX</HU_X3*>
<HU_Y3*>XXXXXX</HU_Y3*>
<HU_Z3*>XXXXXX</HU_Z3*>
</HU*>
```

A short example of my ugly function:

```vb
Public Function toObject(ByVal Str_ShipData As String) As ShipData
    Dim shipData As New ShipData
    Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<Item1\*>(.+?)<\/Item1\*>")
    Dim match = regex.Match(Str_ShipData)
    shipData.SHIPMENT_REF_1 = match.Groups(1).Value()
    regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<Item2\*>(.+?)<\/Item2\*>")
    ...
    Return shipData
End Function
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT **

I try to use the XMLDocument but I've the following error :

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2)
<Shipdata xmlns = ''> was unexpected.
```

My new function :

```vb
Public Function XMLtoObject(ByVal Str_ShipData As String) As ShipData
    Dim shipData As New ShipData
    Str_ShipData = "<Shipdata>" & Str_ShipData.Replace("*", "") & "</Shipdata>"
    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = Nothing
    Dim strReader As StringReader = Nothing
    Dim xmlReader As XmlTextReader = Nothing
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ShipData))
    doc.LoadXml(Str_ShipData)
    strReader = New StringReader(doc.OuterXml)
    xmlReader = New XmlTextReader(strReader)
    shipData = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader)
    Return shipData
End Function
```

XML output :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Shipdata>
    <Item1*>XXXXXX</Item1*>
    <Item2*>XXXXXX</Item2*>
    <DOC*>
        <DOC_ID*>XXXXXX</DOC_ID*>
        <DOC_TYPE*>XXXXX</DOC_TYPE*>
    </DOC*>
    <HU*>
        <HU_X1*>XXXXXX</HU_X1*>
        <HU_Y1*>XXXXXX</HU_Y1*>
        <HU_Z1*>XXXXXX</HU_Z1*>
    </HU*>
    <HU*>
        <HU_X2*>XXXXXX</HU_X2*>
        <HU_Y2*>XXXXXX</HU_Y2*>
        <HU_Z2*>XXXXXX</HU_Z2*>
    </HU*>
    <HU*>
        <HU_X3*>XXXXXX</HU_X3*>
        <HU_Y3*>XXXXXX</HU_Y3*>
        <HU_Z3*>XXXXXX</HU_Z3*>
    </HU*>
</Shipdata>
```

For solve this error use this :

```vb
serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ShipData), New XmlRootAttribute("Shipdata"))
```

Other problem : The serializer doesn't fill my List of HU

```vb
Public Property HU As List(Of HU)
    Get
        Return oHUS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of HU))
        oHUS = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: This is what you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Neal I've update my answer.

Comment: This is exactly what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165066/creating-xml-structure-using-xml-attributes

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm new in the community and I do not know really write response but I will try. I'm going to write an answer for help people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XML instead of Regexp if you have string with tag and you like to fill object.

For this, follow this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

- Convert the string to XMLDocument
- Serialize your XML to Object.

A generic function for create XML document with string and fill object.

```vb
Public Function XMLToObject(ByVal Str_Xml As String, ByVal objectType As Type) As [Object]
    Dim obj As [Object] = Nothing
    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = Nothing
    Dim strReader As StringReader = Nothing
    Dim xmlReader As XmlTextReader = Nothing
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    'serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ShipData), New XmlRootAttribute("YOUROOT")) 'If you have root problem
    serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ShipData))
    doc.LoadXml(Str_Xml)
    strReader = New StringReader(doc.OuterXml)
    xmlReader = New XmlTextReader(strReader)
    obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader)
    Return obj
End Function
```

For list attributes, add XmlElement on your property.

Link can help you : [Creating XML structure using xml attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165066/creating-xml-structure-using-xml-attributes)

```vb
<XmlElement(ElementName:="HU", Type:=GetType(HU))> _
Public Property HU As List(Of HU)
    Get
        Return oHUS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of HU))
        oHUS = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Seems a little much, no? `<XmlElement> Public Property HU As List(Of HU)` is enough when property name is the same as element name

Comment: When I remove <XmlElement> my list of HU is empty, but it work with only <XmlElement()> _.

Comment: Right you need the attribute there to deserialize. But you only need the name when the property name and xml differ. You don't need the class as it's in the generic list def already.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<XmlElement>` attribute for properties to be serialized. The type is automatically inferred; no need to specify. Use `<XmlElement("elementName")>` if xml element name is different than property name.

```vb
Public Class Shipdata
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property Item1 As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property Item2 As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property DOC As DOC
    <XmlElement("HU")>
    Public Property HUs As List(Of HU)
End Class

Public Class DOC
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property DOC_ID As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property DOC_TYPE As String
End Class

Public Class HU
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property HU_X1 As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property HU_X2 As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property HU_X3 As String
    ' ...
End Class
```