# How to serialize a list of list

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to serialize a list of list but i get *System.InvalidOperationException*
in

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(List.GetType());
```

this is my class

```
public class ListDevis
{
    public ListDevis()
    {
        list = new BindingList<Devis>();
    }
    private BindingList<Devis> list;

    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Devis", Type = typeof(Devis))]
    public BindingList<Devis> List
    {
        get
        {
            return list;
        }

        set
        {
            list = value;
        }
    } 
    public void ChargerList(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(List.GetType());
        if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader streamR = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    List = (BindingList<Devis>)xmlSer.Deserialize(streamR);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void SauvegarderList(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListDevis));
        using (StreamWriter streamW = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath))
        {
            xmlSer.Serialize(streamW, List);
        }
    }
}
public class Devis
{
    public Devis()
    {
        commandes = new BindingList<Commande>();
    }

    private string code;
    private string codeClient;
    private DateTime dateDevis;
    private BindingList<Commande> commandes;
    private string statut;

    [DisplayName("Code Devis")]
    public string Code
    {
        get
        {
            return code;
        }

        set
        {
            code = value;
        }
    }
    [DisplayName("Code Client")]
    public string CodeClient
    {
        get
        {
            return codeClient;
        }

        set
        {
            codeClient = value;
        }
    }
    [DisplayName("Date Creation")]
    public DateTime DateDevis
    {
        get
        {
            return dateDevis;
        }

        set
        {
            dateDevis = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Commandes", Type = typeof(Commande))]
    public BindingList<Commande> Commandes
    {
        get
        {
            return commandes;
        }

        set
        {
            commandes = value;
        }
    }
    [DisplayName("Statut")]
    public string Statut
    {
        get
        {
            return statut;
        }

        set
        {
            statut = value;
        }
    }

}    
public class Commande
{

    private string codeProduit;
    private string libelle;
    private float prixU;
    private int qte;

    public Commande(string codeProduit, string libelle, float prixU, int qte)
    {
        this.CodeProduit = codeProduit;
        this.Libelle = libelle;
        this.PrixU = prixU;
        Qte = qte;
    }
    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "CodeProduit")]
    public string CodeProduit
    {
        get
        {
            return codeProduit;
        }

        set
        {
            codeProduit = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "Libelle")]
    public string Libelle
    {
        get
        {
            return libelle;
        }

        set
        {
            libelle = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlElement(DataType = "float", ElementName = "Prix")]
    public float PrixU
    {
        get
        {
            return prixU;
        }

        set
        {
            prixU = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlElement(DataType = "int", ElementName = "Qte")]
    public int Qte
    {
        get
        {
            return qte;
        }

        set
        {
            qte = value;
        }
    }
}
```

my full exception is this /
Une exception non gérée du type 'System.InvalidOperationException' s'est produite dans System.Xml.dll

Informations supplémentaires : Une erreur s'est produite lors de la réflexion du type 'GestionFacturationCore.ListDevis'.

Comment: i had something like that - here is how it done http://stackoverflow.com/a/40165240/1704458

Comment: i used this methode and it didn't work i think the probleme is from the public List<Class3> List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize Class1 you have to provide its type to XmlSerializer constructor

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));
```

You have a method:

```
public void SauvegarderList(string xmlFilePath)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListDevis));
    using (StreamWriter streamW = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath))
    {
        xmlSer.Serialize(streamW, List);
    }
}
```

The *List* variable is of type *BindingList< Devis >* but you are serializing it as a *ListDevis* - change XmlSerializer constructor invocation to:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<Devis>));
```

Also you need to add a parameterless constructor to the Commande class.

Comment: i did this but in the end i have the same System.InvalidOperationException if i mark the  public List<Class3> List { get; set; } as internal it will compile

Comment: So can you post your code and the full exception you have